# List if list to a array of objects

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, dart

I am trying to map a list of list to an array of objects. The list looks like this`[[1592870400000,0],[1592524800000,2],[1592352000000,0],[1592179200000,0],[1591920000000,0],[1591833600000,0],[1591574400000,0],[1591228800000,0]]`
I want map it to an array of objects `class RiskTrend {
final int riskScore;
final int dateTime;

RiskTrend({this.riskScore, this.dateTime});
}`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to iterate over the original list and add the elements to your new list.

```
List<RiskTrend> list = new List<RiskTrend>();
for(var i = 0; i < original.length; i++){
    list.add(new RiskTrend(original[i][0],original[i][1]));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate the help

Comment: If you could accept the answer please, that'll be great :)